# Image links breaking when update images on Symfony built website

Tags: php, image, symfony

I'm working on a website built in Symfony, where the image links are stored in a database (the page I'm working on is database driven) and the actual images are in an images folder. Several images have been added to the page recently, but are not showing up on some computers (even when I go to the image directly, I'm getting a 404 error). I've tried deleting the cache folder, and I've checked the naming of the images to make sure they're consistent with the images on the page that are working. Does anyone know what could be preventing the images from being displayed correctly?

Comment: Things that could be preventing images from being displayed: Permission errors, you're hitting an incorrect URL, tiny gnomes running around your file system hiding files. Start looking at web server and php error logs and see what sort of information you can find.

Comment: In a browser have you tried right-clicking on the image and selecting "inspect" and then checking the "src" of the `img` tag and then pasting that in a browser to see if you see the actual image? That should work, unless the path is wrong or there are permission issues.